# how to make jackson serialize enum with name

Tags: java, jackson

I want to serialize object using jackson `api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2'`, this is the code:

```
WebSocketMsg resp = new WebSocketMsg(MsgType.USER_CHAT,responseMsg );
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String resultJson= objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resp);
```

now the serialize `WebSocketMsg` enum using value, is it possible to make it using the enum name? This is the enum define:

```
@Schema(implementation = MsgType.class)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum MsgType {
    HEARTBEAT(1, "heartbeat")
}
```

I have tried to add `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)` but still could not work. This is the `WebSocketMsg` define:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketMsg {
    private MsgType msgType;
    private String msg;
}
```

the json I want may look like:

```
{
msgType: "HEARTBEAT",
msg: "balabala....."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove the `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)`, you'll have the desired format:

```
@Test
void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    WebSocketMsg resp = new WebSocketMsg(MsgType.HEARTBEAT, "test-msg");

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String resultJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resp);

    assertThat(resultJson).isEqualToIgnoringWhitespace("""
        {
            "msgType":"HEARTBEAT",
            "msg":"test-msg"
        }
        """);
}
```

However, if you keep this annotation, the enum will be displayed like an object. Therefore, the resulting json will be:

```
{
    "msgType": {
        "nr":1,
        "value":"heartbeat"
    },
    "msg":"test-msg"
}
```